# Multitenant Architecture in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, architecture, frameworks, rubygems, multi-tenant

Please let me know the best books available for Implementing Multitenant Architecture in Ruby on Rails.
Is there any gem or framework available for same?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no books just yet, but there's an interesting talk on the subject http://aac2009.confreaks.com/06-feb-2009-14-30-writing-multi-tenant-applications-in-rails-guy-naor.html

and there's a gem you can use for it.

https://github.com/wireframe/multitenant

Comment: As per the video, it is suggested to use postgrese rather than Mysql. I am actually already using Mysql and very comfortable with it and don't want to switch to Postgrese as I am running out of deadlines, if I put a learning curve of Postgrese into account. Will that Multitenant GEM work Mysql? or is there any other GEM that is working fine for Mysql and Datamapper / Active Record as a ORM.

Comment: it should work, it's merely adding tables to the database and a column to the the models that use that tables

Answer (score 2):

I will make a useful list for a seminar slide. (http://goo.gl/cJBJG it is Turkish) .

GEMS

- https://github.com/wireframe/multitenant
- https://github.com/influitive/apartment
- https://github.com/ErwinM/acts_as_tenant

Articles

- http://samuel.kadolph.com/2010/12/simple-rails-multi-tenancy/
- http://samuel.kadolph.com/2011/12/simple-rails-multi-tenancy-ii/
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479086.aspx
- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cloud/library/cl-multitenantsaas/
- http://ecomcanada.wordpress.com/2011/06/29/multi-tenancy-in-cloud-computing/
- http://blog.jerodsanto.net/2011/07/building-multi-tenant-rails-apps-with-postgresql-schemas/

Open Source Repos which use ROR

- https://github.com/lab2023/dudupress
- https://github.com/kebab-project/kebab-revolution

Videos

- http://aac2009.confreaks.com/06-feb-2009-14-30-writing-multi-tenant-applications-in-rails-guy-naor.html

Best Regards.