# Variable Namespacing

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Let's say I have an enterprise application. I have several companies signed up for it. The application helps to manage their workflow.

Would it make sense to create a namespace (by company name)? Or is this a redundancy in some way? Is this a good design decision?

If I were to go through with this decision, how does one implement dynamic, variable-based namespacing?

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :posts, :comments
end
```

Should I make a query in routes.rb? Sounds hacky, but possible...

```
if current_user
    mycompany = current_user.company.name.to_sym
end

namespace :mycompany do
   resources :posts, :comments
end
```

What are your thoughts?

Comment: This is called multitenancy. Check out the [apartment](https://github.com/influitive/apartment) gem to help you with this.

Comment: Also refer to this [Multitenancy Artitecture](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8009517/multitenant-architecture-in-ruby-on-rails)

Comment: Looks like what the doctor ordered. Thanks!

Comment: I found this a useful resource when working with multitenancy: Multitenancy with Rails - https://leanpub.com/multi-tenancy-rails